# Deriving the Kepler's first law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/IoWkh2Pgi9s) video lecture for the proof of Kepler $1$st law and lastly left with this differential equation.
$$\frac{d^{2}r}{dt^{2}}-\frac{L^{2}}{m^{2}r^{3}}=-\frac{GM}{r^{2}}$$

Here, $L$ denotes the angular momentum which is constant in this case.
The goal is to solve for the radius and show that it satisfies the equation for ellipse. The video I mentioned tackles the problem by simply substituting the solution and showing angular momentum is constant confirming the solution.

**My question:-**

Is there any rigorous way to solve this differential equation and show that $r(t)$ satisfies the equation for ellipse?

Comment: You transfer the differential equation to this one \begin{aligned}\dfrac{d^{2}u}{d\theta ^{2}}+u=-\dfrac{GM}{L^{2}}\\
u=\dfrac{1}{r}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that Kepler's first law is about the *shape* of the orbit
(i.e. about $r(\theta)$), not about the time-dependence $r(t)$.

For Newton's gravitational equation of motion
$$m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$$
it can be shown that the so-called [Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Mathematical_definition)
$$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{L}-GMm\hat{\mathbf{r}} \tag{1}$$
is conserved.
From this fact you can quite easily [derive Kepler's first law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Derivation_of_the_Kepler_orbits).

Applying the dot product with $\mathbf{r}$ to definition (1) we get
$$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{r}=
  \mathbf{r}\cdot(\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{L})-GMmr \tag{2}$$

By using $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{r}=Ar\cos\theta$ and
$\mathbf{r}\cdot(\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{L})
= (\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p})\cdot\mathbf{L}
= \mathbf{L}\cdot\mathbf{L}=L^2$ we get
$$Ar\cos\theta=L^2-GMmr \tag{3}$$

Rearranging this yields
$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{GMm}{L^2} \left(1+\frac{A}{GMm}\cos\theta\right) \tag{4}$$

This has already the form
$$\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{p} \left(1+\epsilon\cos\theta \right) \tag{5}$$
which is the well-known equation for an ellipse (or more generally: for
a conic section), where $p$ is the radius at $90°$ and $\epsilon$ is the
eccentricity.